# How to clear driver cache for USB-mouse on Mac

Tags: mac, drivers, mouse

My Mac — MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) running macOS Catalina — crashes somewhere between once per day and once per week, when I have too many applications open. When I start it again, then I'm unable to scroll up, on my external [Logitech Mouse](https://www.logitech.com/da-dk/product/m110-silent-mouse). Scrolling down keeps working - it's just scrolling up.

I can get it to work again, by rebooting my machine and clearing the PRAM (holding down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> upon startup). So I'm pretty certain, that it's a software issue.

Here are some facts:

- It has happened about 10-15 times so far, and it's always scroll-up that won't work.
- It's not every time it crashes, but I'd say 80% of the times. My gut feeling tells me that it has something to do with, if I have been scrolling, when it crashes.
- I have tried several different mice, and this is the only mouse it has happened with. But I don't want to switch mouse, since this is the best mouse across all other areas.
- The built-in touch mouse works as it should. It's only my external mouse (the scroll-up feature) that doesn't work.
- I've tried reconnecting the USB-cable. And the USB-cable is connected to an adapter, and I've tried reconnecting that as well.

---

I'm looking for a way where I can 'clear the driver cache' for the mouse? Are there any such thing?

Comment: You don’t have to reset your PRAM. Most of the time this a religious receipe. A simple reboot which reset the USB bus is enough. What is connected on all your USB buses? Did you find any error message USB related in `/var/log/system.log`? If yes add them to your original question.

Comment: If this only happens with one mouse, try perhaps another one of the same model (as you like this model the best).

Comment: Your question is looking for a specific software solution, but I have [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1606839/167207) that addresses the issue as a physical issue because pretty much everything you are describing reads as a physical issue with the mouse being gunked up to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it working with the Mx Anywhere 2s mouse without rebooting (!), by first uninstalling:

- Logitech Control Center
- Logitech Options
- Logitech Unifying Software

And afterwards installing only Logitech Options again. By the way, I used [CleanMyMac](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) to uninstall the application and preference panes, since Logitech drizzle them all over your Mac (*shakes fists furiously!*).

Answer (score 0):

As this only happens with this one mouse and never with other mice,
the most likely conclusion is that this mouse is broken.

A broken mouse cannot be fixed and is not worth the time of a professional
technician.

The best solution is to buy another mouse,
perhaps of the same model as the one you like the best.

Comment: @Zeth: Have you followed my advice?

Comment: It happens with 3 different mice (2 of which are the same model).

Answer (score 0):

### Disassembled and clean out the the gunk on the inside of the mice.

When you say this:

> “Scrolling down keeps working - it's just scrolling up.”

I strongly believe this is a physical issue with the mouse and specifically with the wheel being gunked up in some way based on my own personal experience.

This is not a statement on cleanliness and such but rather — and if you think about it — most uses of the scroll wheel are up, humans shed skin regularly. So the more you scroll up — and exist as a functional human being the more stuff will get into the insides of the mouse and gunk things go.

FWIW, petty much every mouse I have owned — all of them Kensington mice — had this issue. I solved the issue each time by opening up the mice, cleaning up the insides — which were indeed dunked up— and reassembling them. FWIW, I use a MacBook with a trackpad now so don’t use them anymore.